# mount.cifs hangs and becomes unresponsive

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

I'm connected to a CISCO VPN in order to access to a remote Windows Server. I'm using `mount.cifs` to mount a shared folder on this server.

Here's my `mount` script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
stweb="/mnt/stweb"
if ! mount|grep $stweb; then
    sudo mkdir -p $stweb
    sudo mount.cifs //<server IP>/folder $stweb -o uid=1000,gid=1000,user=<myuser>,password=<mypassword>,domain=<mydomain>
fi
```

Here's my `umount` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo umount -a -t cifs -l
```

They work!

But the problem is: sometimes, due to poor network conditions, the VPN connection is interrupted; thus the share stops working. After reconnecting, I usually run my `umount` script and then the `mount` script . But sometimes the `mount` script hangs for a VERY LARGE amount of time at the `mount.cifs` command. I can't event send a CTRL+C to kill the process. The mounting operation works again after a system reboot.

Rebooting at this situation is time consuming and unproductive. Any ideas of what is happening? Which logs could I check?

BTW, I'm on Wily, but the problem was already there when I was using Ubuntu 14.10.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This problem has been around for at least 10 years, and there still seems to be no way to fix it. I've tried `umount -l xxx`, which doesn't hang, but then we do hang when trying to mount the share. One problem seems to be that you need to remount the share before any process tries to open a file on it. This can be very tricky if you have soft-links pointing into the shared file system.

Even crazier: If the system is stuck, `smbmount` still works without a hitch, even as the `mount` on the same volume is hung for more than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

[This post on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359667) answered it for me.

I had to add `vers=3.0` option in `/etc/fstab` for that mount point.

Comment: this is probably the best answer these days (2012 onward!), and it is likely your SMB share is running vers=3.0 or higher.  

https://kb.netapp.com/Advice_and_Troubleshooting/Data_Storage_Software/ONTAP_OS/What_is_the_default_negotiated_SMB_version_with_various_versions_of_Data_ONTAP_and_Windows_clients

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac hosting the shares it is sometimes necessary to restart file sharing on the Mac (it is simple enough to restart the Mac) before the shares can be mounted again, the culprit will *not* be the Linux client in such a scenario (though it will appear to be as key processes go into *disk sleep* state).  This is also true if something goes wrong on the Mac while the shares are mounted and `umount` becomes unresponsive.  In such a scenario neither `umount -l` nor `fuser -km` will work, both will hang indefinitely.